# Java write individual bytes to DataOutputStream

Tags: java

I'm working on writing individual bytes to a DataOutputStream in java for an HTTP post request. The post is structured like such:

```
/* Init Post */
URL PostToLink = new URL(GeneralArguments.get("PostLink_String"));
byte[] PostData = PutKeyedPostArgs.get("PostBody").getBytes("UTF-8");
HttpURLConnection Post_Request_Connection = (HttpURLConnection) PostToLink.openConnection();
Post_Request_Connection.setDoOutput(true);
Post_Request_Connection.setDoInput(false);
Post_Request_Connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
//Post_Request_Connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
Post_Request_Connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
Post_Request_Connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(PostData.length));
Post_Request_Connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
Post_Request_Connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", UserAgent); // Defined earlier
Post_Request_Connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", CookieVal); // Defined earlier
Post_Request_Connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
Post_Request_Connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
Post_Request_Connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
Post_Request_Connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
Post_Request_Connection.setUseCaches(false);

/* Obtain Write Stream */
DataOutputStream The_Post_Request_Write_Stream = new DataOutputStream(Post_Request_Connection.getOutputStream());
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, PostData.length); // For Debugging

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "before for"); // For Debugging
/* Begin writing byte-by-byte to output stream */
for(int CurrentPostByte = 0; CurrentPostByte < PostData.length; CurrentPostByte++){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, CurrentPostByte); // For Debugging
    byte[] TemporaryByteArray = new byte[]{PostData[CurrentPostByte]};
    The_Post_Request_Write_Stream.write(TemporaryByteArray, CurrentPostByte, TemporaryByteArray.length);
/* Length should always be 1 */
}
```

For some reason it after it writes the second byte (the one at PostData[1]) it gets an index out of bounds error. I cannot seem to find out why.

Any clarifications or help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I can't see your code, but my guess is that `PostDate` only has 0 or 1 element in it, so `PostDate[1]` would be out of bounds.

Comment: You're accessing an array called `BuyData`, not `PostData`...? I don't see anywhere in this code where `PostData` is accessed.

Comment: Why are you writing byte-by-byte instead of just writing all of `PostData` / `BuyData` anyway? Also why use a `DataOutputStream` if you're writing raw bytes?

Comment: Please don't use `C#` variable naming in Java. It makes all of your variables look like static calls.

Comment: @Vulcan My apologies. I renamed some variables before posting here and I forgot to rename that one.

Comment: @CodeChimp The loop is supposed to only loop through the length of the array and yet it's somehow going out of bounds.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch That's not C# variable naming either. Only methods and properties are PascalCased in C#. And static methods aren't in Java anyway.

Comment: @millimoose just testing stuff. I could easily write DataOutputStream.write(MyStringPostBody), but i'd prefer to write it byte-by-byte. Also, what would you recommend if not DataOutputStream?

Comment: @SpencerGrantDoak The `write(byte[], int, int)` method is present on the basic `OutputStream` type.

Comment: @millimoose I'll look into using that instead. Thanks. I doubt that will fix the problem, but at least it'll be a little more robust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your code:

```
byte[] TemporaryByteArray = new byte[]{PostData[CurrentPostByte]};
The_Post_Request_Write_Stream.write(TemporaryByteArray, CurrentPostByte, TemporaryByteArray.length);
```

You are passing the array `TemporaryByteArray` which has a length of `1` (one) to the write method but use the indices valid for the `PostData` array only.

You may fix the code by changing it to:

```
byte[] TemporaryByteArray = new byte[]{PostData[CurrentPostByte]};
The_Post_Request_Write_Stream.write(TemporaryByteArray, 0, TemporaryByteArray.length);
```

or, simpler

```
byte[] TemporaryByteArray = new byte[]{PostData[CurrentPostByte]};
The_Post_Request_Write_Stream.write(TemporaryByteArray, 0, 1);
```

or, even simpler

```
The_Post_Request_Write_Stream.write(PostData, CurrentPostByte, 1);
```

---

But, of course, the best solution would be removing the nonsense loop and write the entire array at once, `The_Post_Request_Write_Stream.write(PostData);` instead of byte by byte.

Comment: That seemed to fix it thanks. I was under the impression that where it called the offset I needed to tell it where in the output stream to write the byte. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

My educated guesstimate is that the problem is here:

```
The_Post_Request_Write_Stream.write(TemporaryByteArray, CurrentPostByte, TemporaryByteArray.length);
```

The parameters to [`write(byte[], int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) are:

- a `byte[]` *buffer* which contains the data to be written
- an `int` *offset* that tells where in the buffer the data you want starts
- an `int` *length* which indicates how many bytes you want to write

The problem lies in the value you pass to the offset parameter. It's `CurrentPostByte`, so in the second iteration you tell it to start reading `TemporaryByteArray` from index `1`. However, `TemporaryByteArray` is always a one-element array, it only has one item int it at index `0`.

You should correct that to:

```
The_Post_Request_Write_Stream.write(TemporaryByteArray, 0, TemporaryByteArray.length);
```

Or, more simply, to:

```
The_Post_Request_Write_Stream.write(TemporaryByteArray);
```

Comment: This also worked, but I have accepted Holger's answer because he posted first. I have upvoted yours though because it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say which line is throwing the exception, but I'm guessing it's

```
byte[] TemporaryByteArray = new byte[]{BuyData[CurrentPostByte]};
```

Looks like you meant to reference PostData here.

Comment: Code was fixed up before you posted your answer. I renamed some variables and missed that one. Anywho, that doesn't seem to be the issue, but thank you for your contribution and my apologies for missing renaming that variable.